# time stamp generation and storage in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp, insert-query

i want the system to generate and store the time stamp to a column in a table when the insert query is fired in MySQL. how to make it happen?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096248/inserting-a-time-into-mysql-database-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT\_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489548/why-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column-with-current-timestamp-in-default-cla)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Insert the current timestamp to a column 'ts' while inserting a row

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (   ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   );
```

> 2. Insert the current timestamp to column 'ts' while inserting a new row and update the current timestamp in column 'ts' while updating data in that row

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
```

More details on the below link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html